# How to change background image in CGI

Tags: c++, css, cgi

Hi i'm having trouble changing the background image of my CGI c++ server page. Right now i am using:

```
cout << "<style> body {background-color: powderblue;}\n </style>\n";
```

This works and changes the background color to powderblue BUT i'd like to figure out how to use my own custom image. I know i need to use:

```
background-image: url("webBackground.jpg");
```

But every thing i try just makes the page blank white. Any hints?

Edit: In my CGI file all i have is this:
string data = "";

```
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    printf("<head><title>Multiplcation</title></head>\n");
    printf("<style>\n");
    printf("body{\nbackground-image: url(\"http://localhost/Animals/webBackground.jpg\");\n}\n");
    printf("</style>\n");
    printf("<body>\n");
    printf("<H3>Multiplication results</H3>\n");
    data += getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    printf("<H1>%s</H1>", data.c_str());
    printf("</body></html>");
```

This produces a white page that has Multipleication results and the query string displayed. For some reason my background-image does not work on the cgi page but will work on my html form page.

Comment: Have you checked the resulting output using „view source“ in your browser?

Comment: i have tried this so far  cout << "<style>\n body {\n background-image: url(\"webBackground.jpg\");\n background-size: cover;\n}\n</style>\n";
no error just a blank white page when it should be displaying this webBackground.jpg image as the background.

Comment: What did the output look like

Comment: Is the jpg in the same directory as the CGI? What‘s in the http access log?

Comment: yes the jpg sits in the same directory as the CGI exe. Not sure where i can see the http access log. I am using IIS.

Comment: Have you tried opening the image manually in your browser

Comment: How can i go about manually opening the image in my browser?

Comment: Is it possible to display a background image?

Comment: Just enter the complete image url in the location bar

Comment: still just a blank white page. Even when i put the complete image path.

Comment: Then the problem is unrelated to your script

Comment: I use the same background for my HTML form page that sends the data to the CGI page. So the image should work, maybe its just the way i'm using standard output to display the html.

Comment: hey have you tried first displaying it as an image..use this------- cout << img().set("src", "/images/webBackground.jpg").set("height", "100").set("width", "100");from here you can get the url..and later set as background image.

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that, i should be able to give it a path to my .jpg image for use in the background-image attribute.

Comment: Can you post an example of what exactly you tried, and the HTML it came out as? In the examples in your post, it's not possible to simply insert the second line of code into the first one, since that would result in a syntax error (because of the nested double quotes).

Comment: I have just posted exactly what is in my cgi file.